# HashMap as a Broadcast Variable in Spark Streaming?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have some data that needs to be classified in spark streaming. The classification key-values are loaded at the beginning of the program in a HashMap. Hence each incoming data packet needs to be compared against these keys and tagged accordingly.

I realize that spark has variables called broadcast variables and accumalators to distribute objects. The examples in the tutorials are using simple variables like  etc.

How can I share my HashMap on all spark workers using a HashMap. Alternatively, is there a better way to do this?

I am coding my spark streaming application in Java.

Comment: You can broadcast any serializable object the same way.

Comment: th keys n values n their inner members should be serializable or not have setters/ marked transient per the mapper notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spark you can broadcast any serializable object the same way. This is the best way because you are shipping data only once to the worker and then you can use it in any of the tasks.

Scala:

```scala
val br = ssc.sparkContext.broadcast(Map(1 -> 2))
```

Java:

```java
Broadcast<HashMap<String, String>> br = ssc.sparkContext().broadcast(new HashMap<>());
```

Comment: This would be a better answer with some explanation behind it, not just code.

Comment: Is there a little more to this? I was using a broadcast variable and it worked once, but upon subsequent calls, the variable returned null. After a little research, I found this post on cloudera's forum (https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Nullpointer-Exception-on-broadcast-variables-YARN-Cluster-mode/m-p/25314/highlight/true#M597) that mentions not having a Broadcast variable as a class member.

Comment: @dmux The problem is that broadcast variable can not be static. It has to be a member variable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a better example of how you would broadcast a HashMap in Java:

In your Spark applcation, you will create or load a HashMap.
Then use Sparksession to broadcast that HashMap.

```
HashMap<String,String> bcMap = new HashMap();
bcMap.put("key1","val1");
bcMap.put("key2","val2");

Broadcast<HashMap> bcVar = this.sparkSession.sparkContext().broadcast(bncFlowConflg, classTag(HashMap.class));
```

And you would need the below class to create a classTag:

```
private static <T> ClassTag<T> classTag(Class<T> clazz) {
    return scala.reflect.ClassManifestFactory.fromClass(clazz);
}
```

And you can refer to the broadcast within Spark functions such as map as below:

```
HashMap<String,String> bcVal = bcVar .getValue();
```

Comment: Your post is a savior for me. The nasty evidence was giving me real hard time.

Comment: Glad I could help!